# WSL2 IP packet source address is modified by windows, causing connection failure

Tags: windows, networking, ip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Here's my network topology:

[image: Network Topology]

I enabled the Routing and Remote Access Service (RRAS) on the `DESKTOP`, using it as a router. Things were going well when I executed `ping 192.168.43.188` on `WSL2` (BTW: I allowed the ICMPv4 in Windows firewall manager). But when I executed `ping 172.31.24.203` on `LAPTOP`, it failed with report "no reply".

So I began to investigate what's wrong in here. I checked the route table, nothing suspicous. Then I used wireshark to capture the packets passing through `172.31.16.1` and `192.168.43.107`:

[image: Wireshark Screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot, the WSL2 did send a reply, but the source address of the IP packet is changed to `192.168.43.107` when sending to `LAPTOP`. In other words, **the ip source is falsified somewhere in `DESKTOP`**.

How could it be? It doesn't make sense, or does it? Is this WSL2 bug or a Windows bug, or there is something wrong with my settings?

Comment: WSL 2 uses NAT, for good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I'm reading between the lines correctly, RRAS is routing traffic for the WSL2 interface?  Otherwise, normally, the laptop wouldn't see the `172.31.16.1/20` network at all, I wouldn't think.

If that's the case, then the problem appears to me to be that the WSL2 switch is not aware of that routing, and still does it's normal NAT, changing the outgoing source address to that of the Windows interface.  Again, as @DanielB and @harrymc have pointed out, this is normal.

In theory, there's a way to disable it, but AFAIK the method requires Windows 11, and so it won't work on Windows Server.  Still, I'll cover it as an option below.

There are several possibilities for routing traffic from the local network into WSL2:

##### An RRAS possibility

I'm throwing this out as a possibility, but I really have no idea if it will work or not.  Given the router and VPN features of RRAS, there may be a way to configure it to "fix" the source address for packets it receives from the WSL2 interface.  I haven't worn my NAT-thinking-hat in a while, so I'd need to find it in the closet to have any higher level of confidence in this.

##### WSL1

This, and the rest of these options, are taken from [my Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403545/1165986) on a related topic.  They don't necessary fix the "route all WSL2 traffic" problem, but rather act on an application/port basis (well, except the last one).

For most networking use-cases like this, WSL1 may be the better option.  While it won't necessarily fix the `ping` use case, network applications/services running under WSL1 are running on the *Windows* network itself, so don't require NAT.

##### SSH Reverse tunnel

Also for individual applications/ports (rather than the entire interface), you can use an SSH connection from WSL2 to the Windows host.  I won't repeat the steps here, but point you to the [original answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403545/1165986).

##### Windows port forwarding

@harrymc points to the Microsoft doc, which recommends Windows port forwarding.  It's certainly an option, but the problem is that, since the WSL2 virtual switch address changes on each reboot, you're constantly having to delete and re-add forwarding rules.  The doc doesn't mention that caveat.

The SSH solution above will always work even when dynamic addresses change.

##### WSL2 Preview with Bridged networking

This would almost certainly work, and disable the NAT, but you can't do it on Windows Server, which I assume you are using due to RRAS.  It is currently only installable on Windows 11 due to the fact that it's the latest mainline with WSLg support.

With the WSL2 Preview installed (which can be done from the Microsoft Store or by downloading a release directly from the [WSL Github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases)), you can follow [this blog post](https://randombytes.substack.com/p/bridged-networking-under-wsl?s=r) (not mine) for instructions on how to enable bridged networking.

Comment: You are right. The laptop didn't see the `172.31.16.1/20` network. Things came to this situation because I manually added a persistent route `172.31.24.203 255.255.255.255 127.31.16.1`. Thanks, you are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The IP address is not falsified by DESKTOP, it just works as designed.

Here are some notes:

- The address segments `172.31.16.X` and `192.168.43.X` are disjoint.
  Under normal condition messages cannot pass from one to the other.
- WSL2 uses the host adapter to reach the network, so any message
  from it will actually come from DESKTOP. Without this IP address,
  other devices will not be able to answer anything coming from DESKTOP.
- WSL2 needs to support the case of multiple instances/distributions
  running in parallel, and be able to distinguish between them.
  For this reason, WSL2 allocates each one a virtual IP inside the
  `172.31.16.X` segment, and does the required translations when messages
  are sent over the network. This is called
  [Network address translation (NAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

What you're seeing is normal, and the only way this can work.
For the outside, your WSL2 distribution is just DESKTOP, nothing else.

If you have added another NAT in the middle, using RRAS, you
can't expect to be able to reach the WSL2-specific IP from the
outside.
WSL2 makes its NAT work for addressing apps from the outside, although with some limitations.
Adding another NAT in the middle just breaks up everything,

See also
[Accessing network applications with WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking).

Comment: Well, sort of - It seems from the question that RRAS has been configured to pass traffic from the *outside* network (the laptop `ping`) to the WSL2 instance.  There may be a "missing" part of the RRAS configuration needed to do an additional NAT on that traffic.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds: I added a note about double-NAT. WSL2 makes its NAT work for addressing apps from the outside, although with limitations. Adding another NAT in the middle just breaks up everything,